# Using ggplot and tidyverse to build a matrix - type scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, visualization

Let's say I have a dataframe in which people respond to 45 items on a Likert scale (5 points) indicating how much they feel anxiety in terms of its "frequency" and "intensity". Therefore, the dataset is composed of 90 items.

Each person has a dataset, and I want to build a plot in which the X-axis is the frequency (with numbers 1 to 5) and the Y-axis is the intensity (with numbers 1 to 5) and each dot is the response of a item.

[image: plot]

I'm really struggling to plot this.

The dataset is

```
df = structure(list(type = c("f1", "i1", "f2", "i2", "f3", "i3", "f4", 
 "i4", "f5", "i5", "f6", "i6", "f7", "i7", "f8", "i8", "f9", "i9", 
 "f10", "i10", "f11", "i11", "f12", "i12", "f13", "i13", "f14", 
 "i14", "f15", "i15", "f16", "i16", "f17", "i17", "f18", "i18", 
 "f19", "i19", "f20", "i20", "f21", "i21", "f22", "i22", "f23", 
 "i23", "f24", "i24", "f25", "i25", "f26", "i26", "f27", "i27", 
 "f28", "i28", "f29", "i29", "f30", "i30", "f31", "i31", "f32", 
 "i32", "f33", "i33", "f34", "i34", "f35", "i35", "f36", "i36", 
 "f37", "i37", "f38", "i38", "f39", "i39", "f40", "i40", "f41", 
 "i41", "f42", "i42", "f43", "i43", "f44", "i44", "f45", "i45"
), item = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 
 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 
 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 
 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 33, 
 33, 34, 34, 35, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 
 41, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45), value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
 0), type2 = c("Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", 
 "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", 
 "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", 
 "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", 
 "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", 
 "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", 
 "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", 
 "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", 
 "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", 
 "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", "Freq", "Int", 
 "Freq", "Int")), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The plot is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = type2, y = value)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Freq", 
                   limits=c("1","2","3","4","5")) +
  scale_y_discrete(name ="Inten", 
                   limits=c("1","2","3","4","5"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we can drop the `type` column and use the `item` column as a key to keep the corresponding observations organized. ggplot2 works most easily with "tidy" data, which for this purpose would be each observed person-intensity combination, which itself has a frequency. To get this, we can use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to convert each pair of `Int` and `Freq` observations into two columns in the same row. Then we can map the Int column to x and the Freq column to y.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  select(-type) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type2, values_from = value) |>
  ggplot(aes(Freq, Int)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2) +
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Freq", 
                   limits=c("1","2","3","4","5")) +
  scale_y_discrete(name ="Inten", 
                   limits=c("1","2","3","4","5"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A base R option would be:

```
colorss <- palette(rainbow(length(unique(df$item)))) # create colors

plot(x = jitter(df$value[df$type2 == "Freq"]), 
     y = jitter(df$value[df$type2 == "Int"]),
     xlab = "Frequency", ylab = "Intensity", 
     pch = 21, bg = colorss, bty = "n")
```

[image]

I know you explicitly indicated `ggplot`, but others may find this base R option more intuitive in this context since you're just plugging in exactly what you want for x and y axes.